# NewForm Custom validation in SharePoint 2013 Custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have one Custom list and many column. In that I want to do validation for People picker column in the list. If people picker 1 and people picker 2 values are equal then I should get message box or alert to block user to select same value for both the people picker field.

Please help me out with javascript or other way?

Answer (score 1):

In "Validation settings" of a list, you can set formula to check your condition. You can select the columns that you want to use with IF condition to check the equality. [Here](http://summit7systems.com/how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-sharepoint-columns/) is a guide to walk you through the process. With this approach, you will be able to show a message at the bottom of the newform dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your Guidance. I am not getting that Peoplepicker column in Insert column list. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation settings in list.

```
 1. Go to List Settings>Validation Settings
 2. In Formula textbox write `IF([FirstPicker column]<>[SecondPicker column],TRUE,FALSE)`
 3. Click OK at the bottom and try it then.
```

That's true that person or group field will not appear in List validation settings. So I think only possible OOTB way to set validation is using javascript on Newform.aspx.

Write your code in **PreSaveAction** function in script editor webpart, read two picker field value and match it and accordingly return true or false.

If return true then item will be save din list otherwise not.

Maybe following link can help you: [blog](http://chandanbadajena.blogspot.in/2011/09/add-javascript-date-validation-into.html)

Comment: Thank you for your Guidance. I am not getting that Peoplepicker column in Insert column list. Please help me out

Comment: see my above comments

Comment: <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> function PreSaveAction(){ code here -- } </asp:Content>

Comment: this is how we have to write our code in content editor web part. ?

Comment: OOTB means? I didnt get...

Comment: Yes, you have to write your code that way only in content editor webpart. Don't include <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> tag in webpart.
OOTB means out of the box (functionalities which already exist in SharePoint)

Comment: The link has code for INPUT field -  var date1 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("INPUT","DateTimeFieldDate","Contract Date"); Can you provide me the code for person or group?

Comment: I tried, Select and INPUT.. didnt work out

Comment: That link was just a reference to get to know how to implement it. You have to write your own javascript to fetch picker1 and picker2 value and then compare it. Accordinglr return true and false form the function!

Comment: getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("INPUT","DateTimeFieldDate","Contract Date"); my questions is instead of INPUT what will come for people picker? I didnt get that in google or in expret forum....